# Dynamically add property to class in order to return a new object in each call

Tags: python, class, dynamic, properties, instantiation

I have a class `Car`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
```

I also have a dictionary `cars` containing names and speeds of some cars:

```
cars = {"bmw" : 250, "ferrari": 350, ...}
```

Now I want to have a container class, which has a `property` for each of these pre-defined cars, so that calling the property creates a **new** `Car` object each time; something like this:

```
class PredefinedCars:
   @property
   def bmw(self):
      return Car(250)

   @property
   def ferrari(self):
      return Car(350)

   ...
```

But I don't want to write down a `property` for each car in the dictionary, because there are too many of them, and also the dictionary can change. Instead, I want to dynamically add all those `properties` during instantiation.
I have tried this:

```
class PredefinedCars:
    def __init__(self, cars):
        for name, speed in cars.items():
            setattr(self, name, Car(speed))
```

This creates the objects as intended:

```
>>> predef_cars = PredefinedCars(dic)
>>> predef_cars.bmw.speed
250
>>> predef_cars.ferrari.speed
350
```

However, each time I call `predef_cars.bmw` for example, the same object is returned:

```
>>> predef_cars.ferrari
<__main__.Car at 0x1145cba30>
>>> predef_cars.ferrari
<__main__.Car at 0x1145cba30>
```

Also, the attributes can be re-assigned, which is not what I want:

```
>>> predef_cars.ferrari = 0
>>> predef_cars.ferrari
0
```

Another solution I tried was this:

```
class PredefinedCars:
    def __init__(self, cars):
        for name, speed in cars.items():
            setattr(PredefinedCars, name, property(lambda self: Car(speed)))
```

This fixes both previous problems, namely that now in each call, a new object is returned:

```
>>> predef_cars = PredefinedCars(dic)
>>> predef_cars.ferrari
<__main__.Car at 0x1145e76a0>
>>> predef_cars.ferrari
<__main__.Car at 0x1145ea3d0>
```

and the `property` cannot be re-assigned:

```
>>> predef_cars.ferrari = 1
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

However, now there is a new problem, namely that all cars are being instantiated with the last `speed` value:

```
>>> predef_cars.ferrari.speed
350
>>> predef_cars.bmw.speed  # Should return 250, but returns 350 also:
350
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve my problem by using `partial` from `functools`:

```
from functools import partial


class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed


class PredefinedCars:
    def __init__(self, cars):
        def car_gen(self, speed):
            return Car(speed)
        for name, speed in cars:
            setattr(PredefinedCars, name, property(partial(car_gen, speed=speed)))

cars = (("ferrari", 350), ("bmw", 250))

prefed_cars = PredefinedCars(cars)
```

However, I still don't understand what the actual issue was, and how using `partial` solved the problem; some explanation would be much appreciated.